# Apache Spark over HBase Rest API

Tags: rest, apache-spark, hbase

I have seen a lot of examples of Apache Spark being used on HBase. All of the examples that I could find used the Java API for HBase. I wasn't able to find any example with the Rest API.

So I wanted to know if it is at all possible to use Spark with the [Rest API](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html) for HBase? If yes where do I get information about it?

Comment: Can you give more information about your task? Why you need to use REST instead of Java API?

Comment: @Lagrang, I had already implemented my existing setup (writing into HBase and a bit of basic querying) using the REST API. So I was just wondering if I could continue to do that. I can always restart using the Java API, but I just wanted to make sure that Spark with Rest API is impossible (or impractical) before doing that.

Comment: As I know, currenlty Spark has built-in HBase support only using Java API.